# Delete repeating section item programmatically by index in macros of docx file?

Tags: vba, ms-word, docx

I have a word template with a content controls wrapped inside a repeating section content control.I need to create a button to delete items repeater, such as the addition of.

I'm trying to figure out how to delete a repeating section item. But in this case - I delete always the last item. But, I want to be able to remove the item the user has chosen.

```
Sub delete()
    Dim cc As ContentControl
    Dim Index
    Set cc = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ResolRepeater").Item(1)
    With cc
        .LockContentControl = False
        .LockContents = False
        .AllowInsertDeleteSection = True

        For Index = 1 To cc.RepeatingSectionItems.Count
        If Selection.Range.InRange(cc.RepeatingSectionItems(Index).Range) Or cc.RepeatingSectionItems(Index).Range.InRange(Selection.Range) Then
           Exit For
        End If
        Next Index

        'can't delete, get Run-Time Error '5904': "you can not change the range"
        cc.RepeatingSectionItems(Index).Range.delete

        'this lines always delete last element:
        'cc.RepeatingSectionItems(Index).Range.Select 
        'Selection.Delete

    End With 
End Sub
```

[word template](https://yadi.sk/i/r0vxZeF8uKeMg)

I will be glad to any answer..

Answer (score 1):

You could do this a number of ways, one of which would be to handle the `ContentControlBeforeDelete` event [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836891.aspx)

Alternatively, you could use the current Selection.range, check if the range (include the start and end) have a content control of type `wdContentControlRepeatingSection` and then simply delete the control.

Something like (code not tested):

```
var contentControl = Selection.Range.ContentControls;
if (contentControl.Type == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdContentControlType) 
{
    contentControl.Delete();
}
```